# Where has libtool gone in xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, libtool-xcode

An external build script I have for creating an embedded framework relies on libtool, which was in /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin

To get the framework to build properly, I had to copy libtool into manually
/Applications/Xcode 7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr

Whats the best approach to make this permanent? How about when using Travis CI? I feel like editing xcode is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late for an answer but anyway, it might help someone else in the future. The right way to invoke `libtool` (or any other binary within Xcode's toolchain) would be to use `xcrun` to locate it:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos libtool <libtool_args>
```

Or you could also obtain the actual absolute path to it by calling `xcrun` with the flag `-f` and then do as you please with it:

```
LIBTOOL_PATH=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -f libtool)
```